# MySQL using more memory than allocated in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 machine with 64 GB of RAM that is used both as a web server and for MySQL version 8.0.35. I am using InnoDB, but even if the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable is set to `128MB`, the memory consumption from MySQL is taking most of the 64GB of RAM plus Swap.

The size of the databases is just 5GB. The the access is in the order of several requests per seconds to read, and every ~10 min to write. The tables are nothing big either. Each database can contain 1000 tables with 1000-5000 rows each.

I understand that optimizing the MySQL server would require changing one parameter at the time, monitor, and iterate towards the optimum values. But here it feels that there is something fundamentally wrong that I am missing on the first place.

Any idea on what this could be?

**htop**
[image]

**Database sizes**

```
+--------------------------+---------------+
| DB Name                  | DB Size in MB |
+--------------------------+---------------+
| mysql                    |          17.0 |
| sys                      |           0.0 |
| information_schema       |           0.0 |
| database_1               |        3878.9 |
| database_2               |         227.4 |
| database_3               |           3.1 |
| database_4               |           1.0 |
| database_5               |         937.3 |
| database_6               |           0.0 |
| database_7               |         281.8 |
| database_7               |         280.7 |
| sessions_data            |           0.0 |
| database_8               |          53.7 |
| database_9               |           0.2 |
+--------------------------+---------------+
```

**InnoDB settings**

```
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name                            | Value                  |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| innodb_adaptive_flushing                 | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm             | 10                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index               | ON                     |
| innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts         | 8                      |
| innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay          | 150000                 |
| innodb_api_bk_commit_interval            | 5                      |
| innodb_api_disable_rowlock               | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_binlog                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_enable_mdl                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_api_trx_level                     | 0                      |
| innodb_autoextend_increment              | 64                     |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode                 | 2                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size            | 134217728              |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown      | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct              | 25                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_filename              | ib_buffer_pool         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_in_core_file          | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances             | 1                      |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort            | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup       | ON                     |
| innodb_buffer_pool_load_now              | OFF                    |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size                  | 134217728              |
| innodb_change_buffer_max_size            | 25                     |
| innodb_change_buffering                  | all                    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm                | crc32                  |
| innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled             | OFF                    |
| innodb_commit_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct | 5                      |
| innodb_compression_level                 | 6                      |
| innodb_compression_pad_pct_max           | 50                     |
| innodb_concurrency_tickets               | 5000                   |
| innodb_data_file_path                    | ibdata1:12M:autoextend |
| innodb_data_home_dir                     |                        |
| innodb_ddl_buffer_size                   | 1048576                |
| innodb_ddl_threads                       | 4                      |
| innodb_deadlock_detect                   | ON                     |
| innodb_dedicated_server                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_default_row_format                | dynamic                |
| innodb_directories                       |                        |
| innodb_disable_sort_file_cache           | OFF                    |
| innodb_doublewrite                       | ON                     |
| innodb_doublewrite_batch_size            | 0                      |
| innodb_doublewrite_dir                   |                        |
| innodb_doublewrite_files                 | 2                      |
| innodb_doublewrite_pages                 | 4                      |
| innodb_extend_and_initialize             | ON                     |
| innodb_fast_shutdown                     | 1                      |
| innodb_file_per_table                    | ON                     |
| innodb_fill_factor                       | 100                    |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout              | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit           | 1                      |
| innodb_flush_method                      | fsync                  |
| innodb_flush_neighbors                   | 0                      |
| innodb_flush_sync                        | ON                     |
| innodb_flushing_avg_loops                | 30                     |
| innodb_force_load_corrupted              | OFF                    |
| innodb_force_recovery                    | 0                      |
| innodb_fsync_threshold                   | 0                      |
| innodb_ft_aux_table                      |                        |
| innodb_ft_cache_size                     | 8000000                |
| innodb_ft_enable_diag_print              | OFF                    |
| innodb_ft_enable_stopword                | ON                     |
| innodb_ft_max_token_size                 | 84                     |
| innodb_ft_min_token_size                 | 3                      |
| innodb_ft_num_word_optimize              | 2000                   |
| innodb_ft_result_cache_limit             | 2000000000             |
| innodb_ft_server_stopword_table          |                        |
| innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree                | 2                      |
| innodb_ft_total_cache_size               | 640000000              |
| innodb_ft_user_stopword_table            |                        |
| innodb_idle_flush_pct                    | 100                    |
| innodb_io_capacity                       | 200                    |
| innodb_io_capacity_max                   | 2000                   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                 | 50                     |
| innodb_log_buffer_size                   | 16777216               |
| innodb_log_checksums                     | ON                     |
| innodb_log_compressed_pages              | ON                     |
| innodb_log_file_size                     | 50331648               |
| innodb_log_files_in_group                | 2                      |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir                | ./                     |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_abs_lwm              | 80                     |
| innodb_log_spin_cpu_pct_hwm              | 50                     |
| innodb_log_wait_for_flush_spin_hwm       | 400                    |
| innodb_log_write_ahead_size              | 8192                   |
| innodb_log_writer_threads                | ON                     |
| innodb_lru_scan_depth                    | 1024                   |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct               | 90.000000              |
| innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm           | 10.000000              |
| innodb_max_purge_lag                     | 0                      |
| innodb_max_purge_lag_delay               | 0                      |
| innodb_max_undo_log_size                 | 1073741824             |
| innodb_monitor_disable                   |                        |
| innodb_monitor_enable                    |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset                     |                        |
| innodb_monitor_reset_all                 |                        |
| innodb_numa_interleave                   | OFF                    |
| innodb_old_blocks_pct                    | 37                     |
| innodb_old_blocks_time                   | 1000                   |
| innodb_online_alter_log_max_size         | 134217728              |
| innodb_open_files                        | 4000                   |
| innodb_optimize_fulltext_only            | OFF                    |
| innodb_page_cleaners                     | 1                      |
| innodb_page_size                         | 16384                  |
| innodb_parallel_read_threads             | 4                      |
| innodb_print_all_deadlocks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_print_ddl_logs                    | OFF                    |
| innodb_purge_batch_size                  | 300                    |
| innodb_purge_rseg_truncate_frequency     | 128                    |
| innodb_purge_threads                     | 4                      |
| innodb_random_read_ahead                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_read_ahead_threshold              | 56                     |
| innodb_read_io_threads                   | 4                      |
| innodb_read_only                         | OFF                    |
| innodb_redo_log_archive_dirs             |                        |
| innodb_redo_log_capacity                 | 104857600              |
| innodb_redo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_replication_delay                 | 0                      |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout               | OFF                    |
| innodb_rollback_segments                 | 128                    |
| innodb_segment_reserve_factor            | 12.500000              |
| innodb_sort_buffer_size                  | 1048576                |
| innodb_spin_wait_delay                   | 6                      |
| innodb_spin_wait_pause_multiplier        | 50                     |
| innodb_stats_auto_recalc                 | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_include_delete_marked       | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_method                      | nulls_equal            |
| innodb_stats_on_metadata                 | OFF                    |
| innodb_stats_persistent                  | ON                     |
| innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages     | 20                     |
| innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages      | 8                      |
| innodb_status_output                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_status_output_locks               | OFF                    |
| innodb_strict_mode                       | ON                     |
| innodb_sync_array_size                   | 1                      |
| innodb_sync_spin_loops                   | 30                     |
| innodb_table_locks                       | ON                     |
| innodb_temp_data_file_path               | ibtmp1:12M:autoextend  |
| innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir              | ./#innodb_temp/        |
| innodb_thread_concurrency                | 0                      |
| innodb_thread_sleep_delay                | 10000                  |
| innodb_tmpdir                            |                        |
| innodb_undo_directory                    | ./                     |
| innodb_undo_log_encrypt                  | OFF                    |
| innodb_undo_log_truncate                 | ON                     |
| innodb_undo_tablespaces                  | 2                      |
| innodb_use_fdatasync                     | OFF                    |
| innodb_use_native_aio                    | ON                     |
| innodb_validate_tablespace_paths         | ON                     |
| innodb_version                           | 8.0.35                 |
| innodb_write_io_threads                  | 4                      |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

**Max settings**

```
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name              | Value                |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
| max_allowed_packet         | 67108864             |
| max_binlog_cache_size      | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_binlog_size            | 104857600            |
| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size | 18446744073709547520 |
| max_connect_errors         | 100                  |
| max_connections            | 151                  |
| max_delayed_threads        | 20                   |
| max_digest_length          | 1024                 |
| max_error_count            | 1024                 |
| max_execution_time         | 0                    |
| max_heap_table_size        | 16777216             |
| max_insert_delayed_threads | 20                   |
| max_join_size              | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_length_for_sort_data   | 4096                 |
| max_points_in_geometry     | 65536                |
| max_prepared_stmt_count    | 16382                |
| max_relay_log_size         | 0                    |
| max_seeks_for_key          | 18446744073709551615 |
| max_sort_length            | 1024                 |
| max_sp_recursion_depth     | 0                    |
| max_user_connections       | 0                    |
| max_write_lock_count       | 18446744073709551615 |
+----------------------------+----------------------+
```

**Query settings**

```
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| query_alloc_block_size | 8192  |
| query_prealloc_size    | 8192  |
+------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: MySQL is not the same thing as SQL Server - please sort out your tags

Comment: i believe this kind of question already asked multiple times in dba.stackexchange.com like [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/298911/ram-overflow-in-mysql), [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289775/mysqld-draining-memory-using-way-more-then-assigned-and-not-giving-any-back), or [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321789/mysql-consumes-much-more-memory-than-configured-in-innodb-buffer-pool-size). and there is [a discussion on how big it should be](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size).

Comment: 128Mb is too low, in general for dedicated server it should be set to 70-80% of available RAM, and it must be a multiple of innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size * innodb_buffer_pool_instances.

Comment: But if the issue is the low size of of allocated RAM than I should be seeing performance issues, right? What I see is a full RAM instead, not a RAM with 128MB for mysql. What is the reason for that?

Comment: What is `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';`?  I agree that 128M is too low for that one setting.  I can't tell if `max_connections` is too high -- it leads to more memory being allocated.  Don't even think about tweaking the hundreds of settings one at a time; nearly all of them won't make a noticeable difference.  9.8% = only 6.328GB.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: When htop shows Sleeping processes for Hours, it is a clear indication that no one has paid any attention to releasing the processes, when completed.  Google search for 'MySQL connect, process, close tutorial' and ensure your developers are getting all 3 functions completed before going for coffee.  A 30 second General Log will likely confirm no one is causing a 'Quit' to be recorded in the General Log when the processing is truly completed.  The result is processes with resource not released in a timely manner.  WAIT TIMEOUT, when expired will get the process OFF the HTOP list.

Comment: @RickJames `Max_used_connections` gives 152, and I have `max_connections` to 151.

Comment: @marcos - That implies that sometimes it ran out of connections.  152 clients are probably taking up a lot of RAM.  It is not normal to allow that many clients to be active at once, what type of app is it?